# Iterate over dataframe within condition append list

Tags: python, pandas

I am appending rows to a pandas DataFrame within a for loop. I want to check all date shift in my ab file :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,3],
                 'DATE_FIRST':['01/04/2020','01/05/2020','01/05/2020',
                         '01/06/2020','03/06/2020'],
                 'DATE_LAST':['05/05/2020','05/05/2020','02/06/2020',
                          '02/06/2020','05/06/2020']})

    id  DATE_FIRST  DATE_LAST
0   1   01/04/2020  05/05/2020
1   1   01/05/2020  05/05/2020
2   2   01/05/2020  02/06/2020
3   2   01/06/2020  02/06/2020
4   3   03/06/2020  05/06/2020
```

The shift in this example is that ID :1 at index 0 its DATE_LAST is greater than the DATE_FIRST of index 1. Same for ID 2 on the other hand ID 3 is correct.

The result of the loop should be like this for **df** :

```
id  DATE_FIRST  DATE_LAST
1   01/04/2020  05/05/2020
2   01/05/2020  02/06/2020
3   03/06/2020  05/06/2020
```

The result for the list **result** :

[1,2]

The goal is to output any id with anomaly in list **result** and of course to rectify the discrepancy and return a clean file **df**.

The anoam

Could anyone highlight what I am missing to make the append statement work? Here's what I tried to do :

```py
def absence (df):
    i = 2
    result=[]
    line=[]
    while i <= len(df):
        for i in df.id :
            if df["DATE_FIRST"].iloc[i-1] <= df["DATE_FIRST"].iloc[i] <= df["DATE_LAST"].iloc[i-1]:
               if df["DATE_LAST"].iloc[i] <= df["DATE_LAST"].iloc[i-1]:
                    result=result.append(int(df.index[i]))
                    df=df.drop(df.index[i])
                    i = i - 1

                elif df["DATE_LAST"].iloc[i] > df["DATE_LAST"].iloc[i-1]:

                     line= (df["DATE_LAST"].iloc[i-1] == df["DATE_LAST"].iloc[i])
                     result=result.append(int(df.index[i]))
                     del(line)
                i = i - 1
            else:
                i = i + 1
        break
    return(result)
    return(df)
```

Comment: Hi Soufiane, can you give an example dataframe of what the end result should look like? Can you give examples of what are anomalies according to you?

Comment: Hi it's more clear now ? thank you

Comment: I've added an example of your starting df to get it a bit more clear. Why should row 1 and row 3 be deleted from your df? This is still unclear to me. Can you explain why these are anomalies and why they should be removed from your df?

Comment: Yes thank you, to avoid the gap between the DATE_FIRST and DATE_LAST of the absence of the same ID. I modified the desired result

Comment: The cases of anomalies are described in my loops

Answer (score 1):

Your anomalies aren't completely clear to me, but a solution like this should get you in the right direction.
 My guess is also that you want to look at this per ID.
I'm using [.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to look at the previous row.
One thing to keep in mind, when using pandas: try not to use for loops, they can really make things slow.

Working example of code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1, 1, 2, 2],
    'DATE_FIRST':['01/04/2020','01/05/2020','01/05/2020','01/06/2020'],
    'DATE_LAST':['05/05/2020','05/05/2020','02/06/2020','02/06/2020'],
})

df['DATE_FIRST'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_FIRST'], dayfirst=True)
df['DATE_LAST'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_LAST'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'DATE_FIRST', 'DATE_LAST'])

df['previous_date_first'] = df.groupby('id')['DATE_FIRST'].transform('shift')
df['previous_date_last'] = df.groupby('id')['DATE_LAST'].transform('shift')

rows_to_delete = (
    (df['DATE_FIRST'] > df['previous_date_first']) 
    & (df['DATE_LAST'] <= df['previous_date_last'])
)
    
df[~rows_to_delete]

    id  DATE_FIRST  DATE_LAST
0   1   2020-04-01  2020-05-05
2   2   2020-05-01  2020-06-02
```

Comment: well you can change variable rows_to_delete to whatever condition you want it to be, maybe you have to try and change it a bit